# What is the pythonic way to create a singleton class?

Tags: python-3.x, flask

I started using Python and Flask for my web servers, and I was wondering if there is a Pythonic way and best practice of managing my class instances.

For instance, if I have a stateless class called `AuthService` and I am using it in multiple places, I want to avoid creating the class multiple times, what is the best practice in Python for this case?

Comment: If it's stateless, why do you even need a class?

Comment: in case I want to extend this class functionality or inherit some functionality from other classes in the future, in object-oriented programming I am using classes everywhere

Comment: @JawadAzzam "*in object-oriented programming I am using classes everywhere*" - you shouldn't. You should be using **objects** everywhere.

Comment: @JawadAzzam "*in case I want to extend this class functionality or inherit some functionality from other classes in the future*" - YAGNI. Also, (stateful) singletons don't work well with inheritance

Comment: Just don't. It's a wholly unnecessary pattern in Python. Just use a module

Answer (score -1):

In Python, a singleton is a design pattern that restricts the instantiation of a class to only one instance.

There are multiple ways to implement a singleton pattern in Python, but one of the most Pythonic ways is to use a metaclass.

Here's how you can use with *AuthService*:

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    _instances = {}

    def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls not in cls._instances:
            instance = super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
            cls._instances[cls] = instance
        return cls._instances[cls]

class AuthService(metaclass=SingletonMeta):
    def __init__(self):
        # Your initialization code here
        pass
```

Now, you can use AuthService as a singleton:

```
auth_instance1 = AuthService()
auth_instance2 = AuthService()

print(auth_instance1 is auth_instance2)  # True
```